# What is the difference between "Run" and "Save" in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

When a download file is prompted in IE, what happens, in background, if I hit Run instead of Save. How IE handles these 2 choices?

Thank you.

Comment: Needs a more specific issue (and IE version) if you'd like to avoid "Run executes the file using the default handler and Save saves the file to disk"-type answers, because that's really all that's happening.

Answer (score 5):

**Run** downloads the file to a temporary location and then executes it. The file is normally deleted on whatever schedule the system has for clearing it's temporary files.

**Save** downloads the file to a temporary location and then moves it to the desired folder for storage. The file can then be run or moved or manipulated or used by the user or system.

Both methods run the file through whatever AntiVirus software is detected on the system prior to releasing it for running or use in it's determined destination directory.